# APT is not working at all: "E: The value 'jessie' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources"

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, software-installation, xubuntu

I'm trying to do run the command `sudo apt-get install ssh`, but when I do I get this error.

[image: sudo apt error]

```
$ sudo apt-get install ssh
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'jessie' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

when I try to `apt update` to fix it I get this.

[image: sudo apt update error]

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                              
Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                      
Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease              
Ign:5 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease                                       
Ign:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Err:7 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports Release
404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.124.204 80]
Get:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:9 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2,365 B]
Ign:9 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC NO_PUBKEY EF0F382A1A7B6500
E: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The value 'jessie' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Anyone run into this before? Is there a way of just wiping apt dependencies and starting anew?

Comment: Hi, for the future, please post terminal information by copying and pasting the relevant output here using this site's [markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help). Posting images makes it difficult for responders to use part of the output in their answers or in requests for clarification.

Comment: And why do you have Debian sources?

Comment: good question, I don't remember trying to add debian sources, do you know how to remove them?

Comment: Open Software and Updates and go to the Other tab.

Comment: ok so I disabled the Debian sources, but still getting the "jessie" error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed a file `/etc/apt.conf.d/10apt` which had things about `jessie` in it and turned out to be causing my problem. Deleting that file resolved the issue.

Comment: How did you figure out that doing that would help? What was in the file?

Comment: I looked up what a typical /etc/apt.conf.d/ directory would look like for ubuntu, and it didn't include 10apt. I also tried editing the "jessie" value in 10apt to make sure that was the file that was restricting my apt calls, and it was.