Using Synaptic in Kubuntu 24.04 - "E: The value 'mantic' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such
Upgraded to Kubuntu 24.04 from 23.10 using shell  commands.
Upgrade seemed to go to completion.
SOLVED - Synaptic now unusable and displays (when invoked):
E: The value 'mantic' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources E: _cache->open() failed, cannot continue.

2022-0521- discovered Synaptic has their control file in /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf.
last line was set to:  DefaultDistro "manic";
I edited line to read: DefaultDistro "noble";
Now Synaptic works again

Maybe here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190341/apt-is-not-working-at-all-e-the-value-jessie-is-invalid-for-aptdefault-re read also all the links there
